# jquery autocomplete remote source tried EVERYTHING !! but no good

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, datasource

i have been trying to implement jquery ui autocomplete feature.. and the basic html code is xactly the same as given on-
  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

I have tried all combinations/ code snippets for "search.php" such as-

1)

```
<?php 

if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

// connect to the database server and select the appropriate database for use
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('research');

$rs = mysql_query('select uname,email,password from login where uname like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by uname asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

// loop through each zipcode returned and format the response for jQuery
$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['uname'] .', '. $row['password'] .' '.$row['uname'] ,
            'value' => $row['uname']
        );
    }
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

2)

```
<?php 
include("includes/connect.php");

$query = "SELECT uname from login WHERE uname LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['term']) . "%'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

foreach($row as $val)
    $tab[] = $val;

}

print json_encode($tab);
?>
```

3)

```
<?php

include("includes/connect.php");

$term = $_REQUEST['m']; // where name of the text field is 'm'
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname LIKE '%$term%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$arr = array();
while($obj = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $arr[] = $obj['nome'];
}

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

But still nothing is working !! that is when i type into the text box for autocomplete there are no results shown. what could be the error ? are there any alternative solutions ?? Please help !!!

Comment: Please help is not a question.

Comment: Attempt 1 looks like it should work. What do you see when you debug using Firebug or another tool?

Comment: @TurboJ- sure please help is not a question .. the whole question is displayed above 'please help'- which requests u to point out any errors in the code or provide alternative solutions !

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker- attempt 1 is not working. none of the tools including google developer show any error. but still when i type into the text box, the ajax does not show any results.

Comment: @Arjun: Does the SQL query itself return any results?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker- the sql query is itself fine.. i ran it in the sql prompt of mysql window, nd it returns the corresponding tuples..

Answer (score 0):

The variable that you pass into json_encode must be an array of strings.
e.g. ["red","green","blue"]
or an array of object literals e.g. [{"value" : "red"},{"value" : "green"},{"value" : "blue"}]

Each time through the loop you need to append the item to the existing items.

I notice, in all 3 code snippets, that you assign the current item to your array variable, instead of appending it. When the loop completes, the only item in your array will be the item processed most recently by the loop.

So unless what you type in the field matches that one item, the autocomplete isn't going to show anything.

Here is my PHP code to build an array of strings before sending it back to the file that made the request.

```
    $fetchedArtists = $db->query($queryToGetArtists );

    $json = '[';
    $first = true;

    while($row = $fetchedArtists->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if (!$first) 
        {
            $json .=  ',';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $first = false;
        }

        $artist = $row['artistName'];     
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$artist.'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
    echo $json;
```